# fetch line in a file if first column match from another file?

Tags: linux, bioinformatics

I have two text files (tab delimited). I am looking to fetch a line from file 2 if first column or ID matches in file 2. Example is below:

File 1:

```
115
147
222
322
```

File 2:

```
0   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
1   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
22  GACGGCA 
34  AAAAAATTTTTTTTAAAAAAAAAAAAA
25  GACGGCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
115 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGGGGGGGGGAAAAAAA
147 GGGGGGGGTTTTTTTTTAAAAAAAA
222 GACGGGAA
322 AAAAAATTTTTTTTAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
115 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGGGGGGGGGAAAAAAA
147 GGGGGGGGTTTTTTTTTAAAAAAAA
222 GACGGGAA
322 AAAAAATTTTTTTTAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: I'm certain this is an exact duplicate of a previous question but I can't find it: I'll just leave this here for now: `awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' File1 File2`

Comment: I have tried this but not working, output file has 0KB space.

Comment: Is there any specific file format that I should use with this command like CSV.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that your files (or at least `File1`) have DOS-style CRLF line endings. Either convert them to Unix-style LF endings or add `-vRS='\r\n'` to the awk command.

Comment: This command only shows the last row entry.

Answer (score 0):

A Python solution:

```py
with open('file1.txt') as f1:
    ids = set(f1.read().splitlines())

with open('file2.txt') as f2, open('file3.txt', 'w') as f3:
    lines = f2.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        id = line.split()[0]
        if id in ids:
            f3.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Hi, these are not working, please suggest any one line command to perform this task.

Comment: Hi, I have tried with different several awk commands for this output but not getting, please suggest a code.